# Unity3d move camera using mouse wheel

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera

I am trying to make simple product visualisation. And I want to zoom or move camera towards the object. My code looks like this:

```
    public class mouseMover : MonoBehaviour {

        public Transform target;
        public float speed;


        void Update () {

            if (Input.GetAxis ("Mouse ScrollWheel") < 0) {
                float scroll = Input.GetAxis ("Mouse ScrollWheel");

                transform.LookAt (target);
                transform.Translate(0, 0, scroll * speed, Space.World);


            }

            if (Input.GetAxis ("Mouse ScrollWheel") > 0) {

                float scroll = Input.GetAxis ("Mouse ScrollWheel");
                transform.LookAt (target);
                transform.Translate(0, 0, scroll * speed, Space.World);
            }

    }

}
```

But when I try to zoom, it just "fly" around the object and when camera get on the another side of object, it starts to recede.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you use Space.World instead of Space.Self :

```
void Update ()
{
    float scroll = Input.GetAxis ("Mouse ScrollWheel");
    transform.LookAt (target);
    transform.Translate(0, 0, scroll * speed, Space.Self);
}
```